# How use the value of one column to check the values of another row?

Tags: mysql, view

I have to create a view that shows employee information for employees who are supervised by female supervisors. I have to display EMP_NUM, EMP_TITLE, EMP_FNAME, EMP_LNAME, and the manager’s employee number,
last name, and title.

The code that I tried only gives me the manager information for Lewis.

Below is a picture of the table EMP.
[empTable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z29NX.png)

```
CREATE VIEW empSalary AS 
  SELECT EMP_NUM007, EMP_TITLE, EMP_FNAME, EMP_LNAME, EMP_MGR, 
    (SELECT EMP_LNAME FROM EMP WHERE EMP_NUM007 = EMP_MGR), 
    (SELECT EMP_TITLE FROM EMP WHERE EMP_NUM007 = EMP_MGR) 
  FROM EMP 
  GROUP BY EMP_NUM007;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a self join on the table:

```
select 
  e.emp_num, e.emp_title, e.emp_fname, e,emp_lname,
  m.emp_num, m.emp_title, m.emp_fname, m.emp_lname 
from emp e inner join emp m
on m.emp_num007 = e.emp_mgr
where m.emp_title = 'Mrs.'
```